# Code coverage missing a branch if a function takes reference parameter

Tags: c++, reference, code-coverage

I have a following function which takes a reference parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

class A { static void TestA(const int &y) };

void A::TestA(const int &y) { std::cout << y; }

int main()
{
   A::TestA(2);
   return 0;
}
```

In my (lcov) code coverage with google unit tests, it is saying missing a branch with TestA() function, and symbols list have a stack_chk_fail symbol added. If I change the function parameter to non-reference then coverage is 100%.

I am using g++ compiler.

Am I missing anything ?

Thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using? Which version of it? What flags are you using when building? What optimization level? And have you checked the generated code, to see what it really does?

Comment: You mean that when you run this short program through your test-coverage tool, it flags something? If not, why are we seeing this program instead of a proper [mcve]?

Comment: what is "my code coverage" ? Unclear what you are asking, you already state in the question what you are missing

Comment: ok ok ... my first comment was wrong. I can reproduce this on my system.

Comment: @StoryTeller I have updated my code, and added details of my test.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler inlines `Test` into `main` (because that's what a good compiler does). However, it also *has* to create code for `Test` because it has external linkage. Effectively, the code for the function exists twice: Once inlined into `main` and once in the code for `Test` that the linker can link with other compilation units.

If your compiler is bad with code attribution (in the debug symbols) for inlined functions (hello MSVC?) then your profiler will give you exactly the result you see: Executing the program does not lead to coverage for `Test` because no piece of the binary that is executed (i.e. `main`) has any line attribution into `Test`.

Changing the parameter type may affect inlining, but it's more likely that it changes how debug symbols are generated.

To verify this, step through the program with a debugger, with a breakpoint in `Test`. If that breakpoint is not hit when running `main`, your coverage tool won't see coverage for that line either. Or, if you really want, look into the debug symbols manually to see which lines have attribution. In Visual Studio you can also look at the disassembly while debugging (it will show the associated code lines).

For the above reasons you will generally get more reliable coverage results if you do coverage runs with debug builds (where e.g. inlining won't happen).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I have updated my code with better example and more details about my test. Can you check again ?  I was able to hit the breakpoint btw. Also why it working fine when it is non-reference pointer?